# Can I set key length for OpenSSL 3des?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl, 3des

I want do these

```
  require "openssl"
  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('des3')
  decipher.decrypt
  decipher.key = "11111111"
```

But it throws `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: key length too short`

I have tried to set the key length by `des.key_len = 8`, it throws `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: invalid key length` error.

Comment: 3DES has a key length of 24 bytes however there is a two-key variant with a 16-byte key commonly referred to as two-key 3DES where the first 8-bytes of the key are repeated for the last 8-bytes, this mode is deprecated. If you want to use a 8-byte key just use DES which should not be used, it is superseded by AES. DES encryption should **not**  be used in new work.

Comment: Triple DES with an 8 byte key could be equivalent to DES if EDE (encrypt-decrypt-encrypt) is used or it could be a valid Triple DES key if EEE (encrypt-encrypt-encrypt) is used. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OpenSSL ruby documentation:

> key_length = integer → integer
>
> Sets the key length of the cipher. If
>   the cipher is a fixed length cipher then attempting to set the key
>   length to any value other than the fixed value is an error.
>
> Under normal circumstances you do not need to call this method (and
>   probably shouldn’t).
>
> See EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length for further information.

And as **Triple Des** *is* a cipher with fixed key length (168-bit ~ 24-bytes), you get an error.

Comment: The answer would be more clear if "fixed length cipher" were changed to fixed length key, 168-bit (24-bytes). See the question comment for more information.

Comment: Where can I get `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length `'s value? I can't find it in anywhere...